# Можно ли заставить СЕРВИС в форграунде быть поактивнее когда телефон не активен?

Tags: android, java

Суть. Есть Сервайс с автозагрузкой при включении телефона к тому же в форграунде. В нём описан метод подключения с удалённым сервером (node.js) через сокет. Всё работает. Но к примеру если связь порвется то в сервисе указанно сделать реконнект через 20 секунд простоя, но это условие не соблюдается. Реконнект может произойти через минуту, две, десять. Если приложение активно то всё работает как часы. Это особенность спящего режима телефона или можно как-то обойти?

Comment: это спящий режим включается. Можно конечно это дело присечь с помощью WAKE_LOCK, но вот только пользователям это сильно не нравится. Батарею садит сильно.

Может Вам нужен Push ?

Comment: Спасибо, почитал про С2DM. НЕ понравилось, гарантий доставки нет, идти может часами. похоже единственный вариант алармменеджер.

Comment: Думаю, что врядли Вы сделаете решение, которое будет более надежное. Если нужен более надежный пуш - тогда берите старые Blackberry - он там через спецсмс работает. Для получения сообщения даже к интернету подключенным не нужно быть.